# Change a UIImageView on another ViewController using a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, viewcontroller

This code would work if the Ball UIImageView was on the same View Controller but Ball is on a separate View Controller so it says:

Use of undeclared identifier 'Ball'

How should I go about having the images change for Ball when the Actions on this View Controller are implemented?

```
}
-(IBAction)BallSelect2:(id)sender{
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2fire.png"];

}
-(IBAction)BallSelect3:(id)sender{
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball70color.png"];

}
-(IBAction)BallSelect4:(id)sender{
    Ball.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sawball.png"];
```

Comment: it would be better to pass the UIImage (or the image name string) to the view controller in question, then let that viewcontroller setup the UIImage. if you not sure how to pass objects between viewcontrollers, that particular question gets asked pretty much every day on stackoverflow so im sure you can find out how

Comment: What exactly is `Ball` ?

Comment: Ball is a UIImageView

Comment: Ooh okay. I looked at you're question and at some of the answers and now I'm lost ):

Answer (score 0):

For this you need the shared instance of Ball `UIImageView` for all.

Create the one singleton class which contains UIImageView object, and add that class as subview to other view controllers.

Comment: how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepareForSegue method to set the outlet of UIViewImage in this method when you perform Segue from one viewController to other.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property of UIImage on next view controller where you want to change image and create local object of UIImage on same viewcontroller and pass image name on respective button click

```
 -(IBAction)buttonActions:(UIButton *)sender
 {
    switch (sender.tag) {
    case 0:
        ball_Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2fire.png"];
        break;
    case 0:
        ball_Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball70color.png"];
        break;
    case 0:
        ball_Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sawball.png"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
   }
 }
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender        {
         NextViewController *objnext = [segue destinationViewController];
         objnext.ballImage =ball_Image.image;
}
```

and assign that ballImage to your imageview in NextviewController.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates. Set delegate for

```
// -- declare this on SecondViewController.h
id delegate;

// -- on FirstViewController after you instantiate SecondViewController set the delegate
    secondViewController.delegate = self;
```

And then on the SecondViewController you can call.

```
(FirstViewController*)self.delegate.Ball setImage["your_image"];
```